# .NET Highcharts not applying responsive rules

Tags: highcharts, dotnethighcharts

My responsive rules are not being applied in Highcharts .NET.

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

I want the step=2 to be applied when max width of 460.

I can put step=2 on the x axis in the highcharts object but that results in the chart always having 2 step. I only want this when the responsive condition is applied.

This is my controller code:

```
public ActionResult FundInformation()
        {
            var fondsViewModel = new FondsViewModel();

            List<Series> tmpList = new List<Series>();
            List<string> colorList = new List<string>();

            //var data = fonds.GrafiekData;
            List<double> fondsdata = new List<double> { 49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 54.4, 54.4, 54.4, 54.4, 54.4 };

            List<ColumnSeriesData> fondslist = new List<ColumnSeriesData>();
            fondsdata.ForEach(p => fondslist.Add(new ColumnSeriesData { Y = p }));
            ColumnSeries Cs = new ColumnSeries
            {
                Name = "Fonds",
                Data = fondslist,
                Stack = "ul",
            };
            tmpList.Add(Cs);

            colorList.Add("#CCCCCC");

            var chartId = $"chart{Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")}";

            Highcharts myChart = new Highcharts()
            {

                Colors = colorList,
                Chart = new Chart
                {

                    ClassName = "grafiek",
                    //StyledMode = true,
                    Height = 135,
                    Type = ChartType.Column,
                    Events = new ChartEvents
                    {
                        //Redraw = "function(e) {console.log(this)}"
                    }

                },
                Title = new Title
                {
                    Text = "Fonds"
                },
                Credits = new Credits
                {
                    Enabled = false
                },
                Legend = new Legend
                {
                    Enabled = false
                },
                XAxis = new List<XAxis>
                       {
                            new XAxis
                            {
                                GridLineWidth= 0,
                                Min = 1,
                                Max = Cs.Data.Count(),
                                TickAmount = Cs.Data.Count(),
                                Reversed =  true,
                                StartOnTick = true,
                                Labels = new XAxisLabels
                                {
                                    Enabled= true,
                                    //Step=2
                                }

                            }
                        },
                YAxis = new List<YAxis>
                        {
                            new YAxis
                            {
                                TickAmount = 3,
                                GridLineWidth = 0.5,
                                MinorGridLineWidth = 0,
                                AllowDecimals = false,
                                Title = new YAxisTitle
                                {
                                    Enabled = false
                                },
                                Labels = new YAxisLabels
                                {
                                    Enabled = true,
                                    Format = "{value}%",
                                                                    },
                                StackLabels = new YAxisStackLabels
                                {
                                    Enabled = false
                                }
                            }
                        },
                Tooltip = new Tooltip
                {
                    Enabled = false,
                    Shared = true,
                    Shadow = new Shadow
                    {
                        Enabled = false
                    }
                },
                PlotOptions = new PlotOptions
                {
                    Column = new PlotOptionsColumn
                    {
                        Stacking = PlotOptionsColumnStacking.Normal,
                        PointStart = 1,
                        PointPadding = 0,
                        GroupPadding = 0.03,
                        BorderWidth = 0,

                    },
                    Series = new PlotOptionsSeries
                    {
                        EnableMouseTracking = false,
                        States = new PlotOptionsSeriesStates
                        {
                            Hover = new PlotOptionsSeriesStatesHover
                            {
                                Enabled = false
                            },
                        },
                        DataLabels = new PlotOptionsSeriesDataLabels
                        {

                            Enabled = false,
                            Y = -35,
                            Rotation = 0,
                            Align = PlotOptionsSeriesDataLabelsAlign.Center,
                            Inside = true,
                        }
                    }
                },
                Responsive = new Responsive
                {

                    Rules = new List<ResponsiveRules>
                    {
                        new ResponsiveRules
                        {
                            Condition = new ResponsiveRulesCondition
                            {
                                MaxWidth=460,
                            },
                            ChartOptions = new
                            {

                                XAxis = new List<XAxis>
                                {
                                    new XAxis
                                    {
                                        Labels = new XAxisLabels
                                        {
                                           Step = 2,

                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                            }
                        },
                    }
                },
                Series = tmpList,
            };
            myChart.ID = chartId;


            fondsViewModel.FondsId = chartId;
            fondsViewModel.Chart = myChart;
            fondsViewModel.FondsNaam = "Some name fonds";
            fondsViewModel.LabelFondsBeschrijvingKnop = "Omschrijving";
            fondsViewModel.FondsBeschrijvingContent = "Something something";
            fondsViewModel.FondsBeschrijvingUrl = "Something.com";

            return View(fondsViewModel);



        }
```

And this is my view code:

```
@model WebApplication3.Controllers.FondsViewModel
@using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts.Rendering
@{
    var renderer = new HighchartsRenderer(Model.Chart, "somekey");

}
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div class="pensioen-bij-row verdeling">
    <div class="fondsdetail">
        <div id="@Model.FondsId" class="grafiek"></div>
        @Html.Raw(renderer.RenderHtml(false))
        <button class="fondsbeschrijving">@Model.LabelFondsBeschrijvingKnop</button>
        <div class="beschrijving">
            @Html.Raw(Model.FondsBeschrijvingContent)
            <a class="externe-link" href="@Model.FondsBeschrijvingUrl" target="_blank"><span>@Model.FondsNaam</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Im using Highsoft.Highcharts 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
ChartOptions = new { xAxis = new {
      labels = new { step = 2 } 
} }
```

If this wouldn't help could you share a JS code produced by wrapper?